# Find all the permutations which commute with a given one

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations, permutation-cycles

The exercise goes like this:

> Find all the permutations which commute with $\sigma$ = (1 3 2 5 4) (6 7) in $S_7$.

I am using a standard approach for this kind of problem: $\tau \in S_7$ commutes with $\sigma$ if and only if $\tau\sigma\tau^{-1} =\sigma$. Thus we get:

$$ \tau\sigma\tau^{-1} = (\tau(1)\:\tau(3)\:\tau(2)\:\tau(5)\:\tau(4))\:(\tau(6)\:\tau(7)) = (1\:3\:2\:5\:4)\:(6\:7).$$

What I'm struggling with is how to get $\sigma$ from this equation. How does one determine it by its first element?

I'm a complete begginer with this topic and unfortunately there is not much info on permutations in my native language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is only one way to satisfy $$(\tau(1)\:\tau(3)\:\tau(2)\:\tau(5)\:\tau(4))\:(\tau(6)\:\tau(7)) = (1\:3\:2\:5\:4)\:(6\:7)$$ and that is if first $(\tau(1)\:\tau(3)\:\tau(2)\:\tau(5)\:\tau(4)) = (1\:3\:2\:5\:4)$ and second $(\tau(6)\:\tau(7)) = (6\:7)$.

We have $(\tau(6)\:\tau(7)) = (6\:7)$ if $\tau$ either fixes $6$ and $7$ or swaps them.

As for $(\tau(1)\:\tau(3)\:\tau(2)\:\tau(5)\:\tau(4)) = (1\:3\:2\:5\:4)$, once you pick $\tau(1) \in \{1,2,3,4,5\}$, this condition tells you what $\tau(2), \tau(3), \tau(4), \tau(5)$ must be.

For example, if $\tau(1) = 5$ then $\tau(3)$ must be $4$ (the next term in this $5$-cycle after $5$), $\tau(2)$ must be $1$ (the next term after $4$) and so on.

Comment: So, as far as I understand it, we just pick one particular cycle and, so to say, "shift" it to the side and see what must go where under such condition?

Comment: In this case, yes. There is one complication that doesn't happen in this case. Suppose you started with $\sigma = (1\:2\:3)\:(4\:5\:6)$. Then the $\tau$ that commute with this $\sigma$ could be any of the $9$ permutations that shift $1,2,3$ around and also shift $4,5,6$ around. But they could also swap $\{1,2,3\}$ with $\{4,5,6\}$ and then do one of the above.